# Killing child with SIGTERM

Tags: c, unix, signals, posix, handler

I have 2 programs: **1)** *Father* **2)** *Child*.
When *Father* receives SIGINT (CTRL-C) signal his handler sends a SIGTERM to his child. The problem is that often (not always, don't know why) it shows this error in loop after SIGINT:

```
Invalid Argument
```

Goal of the father is to create a child and then just being alive to be ready to handle SIGINT.

*Father*

```
#include "library.h"

static void handler();

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int value, que_id;
    char str_que_id[10], **child_arg;
    pid_t child_pid;
    sigaction int_sa;

    //Create message queue
    do{
        que_id = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE, ALL_PERM | IPC_CREAT);
    }while(que_id == -1);
    snprintf(str_que_id, sizeof(str_que_id), "%d", que_id);

    //Set arguments for child
    child_arg = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
    child[0] = "child";
    child[1] = str_que_id;
    child[2] = NULL;

    //Set handler for SIGINT
    int_sa.sa_handler = &handler;
    int_sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    sigemptyset(&int_sa.sa_mask);
    sigaddset(&int_sa.sa_mask, SIGALRM);
    sigaction(SIGINT, &int_sa, NULL);

    //Fork new child
    if(value = fork() == 0){
        child_pid = getpid();
        do{
            errno = 0;
            execve("./child", child_arg, NULL);
        }while(errno);
    }

    //Keep alive father
    while(1);

    return 0;
}

static void handler(){
    if(kill(child_pid, SIGTERM) != -1)
        waitpid(child_pid, NULL, WNOHANG);
    while(msgctl(que_id, IPC_RMID, NULL) == -1);
    free(child_arg);
    exit(getpid());
}
```

Goal of the child (only for now in my project) is just to wait a new message incoming from the message queue. Since there won't be any message, it will always be blocked.

*Child*

```
#include "library.h"

typedef struct _Msgbuf {
    long mtype;
    char[10] message;
} Msgbuf;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int que_id;

    //Recovery of message queue id
    que_id = atoi(argv[1]);

    //Set handler for SIGTERM
    signal(SIGTERM, handler);

    //Dynamic allocation of message
    received = calloc(1, sizeof(Msgbuf));

    while(1){
        do{
            errno = 0;
            //This will block child because there won't be any message incoming
            msgrcv(que_id, received, sizeof(Msgbuf) - sizeof(long), getpid(), 0);
            if(errno)
                perror(NULL);
        }while(errno && errno != EINTR);
    }
}

static void handler(){
    free(received);
    exit(getpid());
}
```

I know from the [man pages on `msgrcv()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/msgrcv):

> The calling process catches a signal. In this case the system call fails with *errno* set to **EINTR**. (**msgrcv**() is never automatically restarted after being interrupted by a signal handler, regardless of the setting of the **SA_RESTART** flag when establishing a signal handler.)

So why does it go to loop printing that error? It should exit in the handler instead it seems that after the handler comes back and (since the `free(received)` ) it doesn't find the buffer of the message setting errno to **EINVAL** .

Comment: Unless you do something special, control-C will kill both the parent and the child.  So I suspect you have a race condition: by the time the parent tries to kill the child, the child might already be dead and gone, resulting in the `Invalid argument` issue.

Comment: @SteveSummit So the problem is that it's not necessary in the father's handler to kill the child. Is it right?

Comment: @G.locurto Well, if it's not necessary for the parent to kill the child, in this case it would seem it's not even necessary for the parent to exist, given that you described the goal of the parent as "create a child and then just being alive to be ready to handle SIGINT".

Comment: @G.locurto But, yes, I believe it's true that in this case it is not necessarily for the parent to kill the child.

Comment: @SteveSummit Even if I had a hundred of children running? It wouldn't change nothing? It would always be unnecessary?

Comment: @G.locurto Under Unix and Linux, at least, and unless you do something special, in this situation hitting control-C will send SIGINT to all processes.  (Keyboard signals go to all processes in the current *process group*.  Unless you do something special, calling `fork` gets you a new process that's in the same process group as its parent.)

Comment: @G.locurto Can you post library.h file also?

Comment: @G.locurto - I wouldn't call `msgctl`, `free`, or `exit` from within a signal handler.  Calling functions not listed as safe in [Signal Actions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03) from within a signal handler is *undefined behavior*.  I don't think that is causing your issue but it is something to be aware of.

Comment: @D.Shawley So how can I do these things safely? I have to call another function that does it?

Comment: @G.locurto You have to set a `sig_atomic_t` global variable that the main loop of your application checks.

Comment: @SteveSummit problem continues even if I make to end the father and before dying the father sends SIGTERM to his child. It is very strange. Almost always child continues to live and I have to kill him by htop.

Comment: @SteveSummit *Unless you do something special, control-C will kill both the parent and the child. So I suspect you have a race condition: by the time the parent tries to kill the child, the child might already be dead and gone, resulting in the Invalid argument issue.*
I don't think it is what happens because **Invalid argument** is reported on line of `msgrcv(..)` of child. In fact it can't be the error because of the control `if(kill(child_pid, SIGTERM) != -1)`, so if kill fails no signal is sent.

Comment: @G.locurto signal handlers are extremely limited in what they can do.  Most of the time you don't want to do more than set a flag that tells your application to respond to the signal. I put together an example on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/HurtfulSeriousLoop) that uses TCP sockets instead of msgrcv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your program.  It invokes undefined behaviour by calling `exit`, `free`, and `msgctl` from within the signal handlers.  The table in the [Signal Actions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03) section of *The Open Group Base Specifications* lists the functions that are safe to call from within a signal handler.  In most cases, you simply want to toggle a "running" flag from within the handler and have your main loop run until it is told to exit.  Something like the following simple example:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


/* this will be set when the signal is received */
static sig_atomic_t running = 1;


void
sig_handler(int signo, siginfo_t *si, void *context)
{
    running = 0;
}


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc;
    struct sigaction sa;

    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = &sig_handler;
    rc = sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
    if (rc < 0) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Waiting for SIGINT\n");
    while (running) {
        printf("... sleeping for 10 seconds\n");
        sleep(10);
    }
    printf("Signal received\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I put together a more complex session on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/HurtfulSeriousLoop) as well.

The other problem is that you assume that `errno` retains a zero value across function calls.  This is likely the case but the only thing that you should assume about `errno` is that it will be assigned a value when a library function returns a failure code -- e.g., `read` returns `-1` and sets `errno` to something that indicates the error.  The conventional way to call a C runtime library function is to check the return value and consult `errno` when appropriate:

```
int bytes_read;
unsigned char buf[128];

bytes_read = read(some_fd, &buf[0], sizeof(buf));
if (bytes_read < 0) {
    printf("read failed: %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
}
```

Your application is probably looping because the parent is misbehaving and not waiting on the child or something similar (see above about *undefined behavior*).  If the message queue is removed before the child exits, then the `msgrcv` call is going to fail and set `errno` to `EINVAL`.  You should check if `msgrcv` is failing *before* you check `errno`.  The child should also be terminating the loop when it encounters a `msgrcv` failure with `errno` equal to `EINVAL` since that is a terminal condition -- the anonymous message queue can never be recreated after it ceases to exist.

Answer (score 1):

(Almost) always `errno` *only* carries a sane value if and only if a function call failed.

This is the case for `msgrcv()`.

From [`msgrcv()`'s documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/msgrcv.html#):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> Upon successful completion, `msgrcv()` shall return a value equal to the number of bytes actually placed into the buffer `mtext`. Otherwise, no message shall be received, `msgrcv()` shall return -1, and `errno` shall be set to indicate the error.

So only use `errno` if `msgrcv()` returned `-1`, else `errno`'s value is undefined and it might very well contain garbage or not ...

The code below does not make sense ...

```
        msgrcv(que_id, received, sizeof(Msgbuf) - sizeof(long), getpid(), 0);
        if(errno)
            perror(NULL);
      } while(errno && errno != EINTR);
```

... and should look like:

```
        if (-1 == msgrcv(que_id, received, sizeof(Msgbuf) - sizeof(long), getpid(), 0))
        {
          /* Only here errno had a well defined value. */
          perror("msgrcv() failed"); /* perror() translates errno into a human readable text prefixed by its argument and logs it to the stderr. */
        }
        else
        {
          errno = 0;
        }
      } while (errno && errno != EINTR);
```

---

This BTW

```
   do{
        errno = 0;
        execve("./child", child_arg, NULL);
    }while(errno);
```

only works as the members of the `exec*()` family of functions *only return* on error. So when the `while`'s  condition is tested then `execve()` *had* failed, though `errno` *had* been set. Here also the initial `errnr = 0;` setting is useless.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Can I ask you some question in pvt?

Comment: @G.locurto: Why not pose your questions openly, that's what SO is made for.